# utilizing Grönwall's inequality to prove a property of two solutions of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Consider the differential equation $\dot{x} = f(t, x)$ with $f$ being a continuously differentiable function from $G \to \mathbb{R}^n$, with $G \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ an open subset. Let $f$ be (globally) Lipschitz on $G$ with respect to $x$, with a Lipschitz constant $L > 0$.

I want to prove: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions of the differential equation $\dot{x} = f(t, x)$ that are defined on an interval $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, then we have that:

$$||x_1(t) - x_2(t)|| ≤ ||x_1(a) - x_2(a)||e^{L(t-a)}$$

for all $t \in [a, b]$.

I was looking at using the [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) to solve this.

I see that, in order to use Grönwall's inequality, I need to show that

$$ ||x_1(t) - x_2(t)|| ≤ ||x_1(a) - x_2(a)|| + L\left\lvert\int_a^t ||x_1(t) - x_2(t)||ds\right\rvert$$

for all $t \in [a, b]$. However, that's where I got stuck. This inequality is obviously true for $t = a$, but how can I show this for $t > 0$? I know that I need to somehow use the fact that $f(t, x)$ is Lipschitz continuous with the constant $L > 0$; but why does that tell me that the integral on the RHS always "grows fast enough"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the absolute value around the integral in unnecessary, since norms are nonnegative, the integral will be nonnegative.

Let's start by creatively adding $0$ and using the Triangle Inequality:
$$\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| = \|x_1(t) - x_1(a) + x_1(a) -x_2(a) - (x_2(t) - x_2(a))\|$$
$$ \leq \|x_1(a) - x_2(a)\| + \|x_1(t) - x_1(a) - (x_2(t) - x_2(a))\| $$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$ = \|x_1(a) - x_2(a)\| + \left\| \int_a^t x_1'(s) - x_2'(s)\,ds \right\| $$
Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to the ODE:
$$= \|x_1(a) - x_2(a)\| + \left\| \int_a^t f(s,x_1(s)) - f(s,x_2(s)) \,ds \right\|$$
Now we use the fact given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103779/proof-involving-norm-of-an-integral) and we get
$$\leq \|x_1(a) - x_2(a)\| + \int_a^t \|f(s,x_1(s)) - f(s,x_2(s))\| \,ds$$
By the Lipschitz condition and monotonicity of the integral:
$$  \leq \|x_1(a) - x_2(a)\| + \int_a^t L \|x_1(s) - x_2(s)\|\,ds $$
and the result follows.