# Show that a system of equations to find a curve based on its curvature and torsion has a unique solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations

Quoted from Pressley's Differential Geometry :

[image]

How to show that the three mentioned equations have a unique solution with initial conditions?

Since $k=k(s)$ and $t=t(s)$ are functions not constants so any try for solving them leads to even more complicated system of equations.

Comment: [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Comment: @achillehui, there are three functions in not-3-independent-equations) to be solved not one.

Comment: The $y$ in the theorem can be vector, the [wiki book entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/The_Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for the theorem spell this out explicitly.

Comment: @achillehui, I started to learn the one-dim case from an easy textbook now so I hopefully can understand the one in wikibook... Thanks.

Comment: @achillehui, I understood all thing but one! Let $x(s)=(T_1(s), T_2(s), T_3(s), N_1, ..., B_1, ...)$ and $f(s,x(s))=(k(s)N_1(s), ..., -k(s)T_1+t(s)B_1, ..., -t(s)N_3)$ then $\frac{d}{ds}x(s)=f(s,x(s))$ together with existence of $L$ (Lipschitz const) implies that $\text{max}_{s \in [s_0, s_1]} (k^2(N_1-N'_2)^2+...+(-tN_3+tN'_3)^2) \le L^2 \text{max}_{s \in [s_0, s_1]} (T_1-T'_2)^2+...+(B_3-B'_3)^2)$. But for the smooth functions of $T$, $N$, $B$ in the (differential geo) text (image in OP) how the existence of $L$ is proven/guaranteed? ( ' means y instead of x , not for derivative)

Comment: @achillehui, I used the definition of norm..

Comment: Let $y = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} T \\ N \\ B\end{smallmatrix}\right]$,  $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & k & 0 \\ -k & 0 & t \\ 0 & -t & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. We are dealing with ODE $\dot{y} = Ay$. At time $s$, what $L$ need to satisfy is  $\|A(s)(y_1(s) - y_2(s))\| \le L \|y_1(s)-y_2(s)\|$ for any $y_1, y_2$. This is equivalent to operator norm $\|A(s)\| \le L$. Since $k(s), t(s)$ is continuous, $A(s)$ is continuous. $\|A(s)\|$ will be continuous and hence bounded over $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. You can take $L$ to $\sup \{ \|A(s)\| : s \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon] \}$

Comment: @achillehui, Thanks! sorry other thing I thought I understood but I can't figure that how norm of integral is $\le$ integral of norm? (in the wikibook) I know that for Euclidean norm (absolute value) in $\mathbb{R}$ but I can't prove that for norm of like $max [a^2+...]^{1/2}$

Comment: in wikibook, the norm in first norm inequality is ordinary euclidean norm. For the proof of integral of euclidean-norm $\le$ integral of euclidean-norm.  see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103779).