# The Triangle Inequality implies that the shortest path between two points is a line segment. (in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Axler)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, triangle-inequality

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

On p.173 in this book, the author wrote as follows:

> Note that the Triangle Inequality implies that the shortest path between two points is a line segment.

I have not read a proof of the above fact yet.

Does a typical proof of the above fact use the Triangle Inequality?
When we prove the above fact by calculus or something, do we need the Triangle Inequality?
Is it true that we cannot prove the above fact without the Triangle Inequality?

Comment: Are we assuming a normed vector space?

Comment: @FelixB. I don't know "normed vector space". I think  the author is saying the Triangle Inequality implies that the shortest path between two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a line segment.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a normed vector space. It is a vector space as it is stable under addition (I can add two vectors and still be in the space). Contrary to the surface of a sphere for example where the shortest path would not be a (straight) line. A norm is just a function measuring the length of a vector with certain properties (one is the triangle inequality). I think that "normed vector space" is likely the weakest assumption possible.

Comment: @FelixB. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

The more that I think about this question, the more I think that the answer is going to be: "By definition".

In order to determine what the shortest path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$ between two points $a$ and $b$ is, we first have to measure the length of a path. Otherwise we can not determine the shortest. So we need a way to map paths to lengths. Assuming we have such a mapping
$$
 \mu: ([0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}_+,
$$
then it is reasonable to assume that the distance $d(a,b)$ between two points $a,b$, should be the infimum of the path lengths over all paths. I.e.
$$
d(a,b) = \inf \big\{\mu(\gamma) \mid\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n \text{ with } \gamma(0)=a, \gamma(1)=b \big\}
$$
cf. [Intrinsic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric). So by definition $\|b-a\|=d(b,a)$ should be equal to the shortest path. If the length of the straight line $\gamma_S(t) = a + t(b-a)$ is equal to $\|b-a\|$ we would be done. Now the question is, with what do we start? With a given length mapping $\mu$ for paths which has the property that its induced distance results in a well defined norm on our vector space? Or should we start with a norm and *define* a length mapping $\mu$ using this norm?

### Starting with a norm

A reasonable definition of a path length might be, that we define straight lines to be equal to the norm. Define the length of polygonal chains to be equal to the sum of its individual line segments and then approximate paths with polygonal chains and define the length of a path to be the limit length of the approximating polygonal chains. Since any path connecting two points is therefore a sum of line segments (in the limit), it follows by the triangle inequality that the straight line connecting these two points must necessarily be smaller. But this is kind of by definition.

### Starting with path lengths ($\mu$)

This is much more tricky, here we have to show that $\mu(\gamma_S)=\|b-a\|$ for the straight line $\gamma_S(t) = a + t(b-a)$. The proof is probably by contradiction: assume that this is not the case and prove that the intrinsic metric of this length measure $\mu$ does not result in a well defined norm. But I currently do not know how to do that.

Comment: Starting with a norm is best, imho  One can then define lengths for merely continuous curves, too. Let $0=t_0<\dots<t_n=T$, where the curve $r$ is parametrized over $[0,T]$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^n\Vert r(t_k)-r(t_{k-1})\Vert$ is the length of a polygonal path approximating our path. If the supremum of these lengths over all polygonal approximations exists, we call the path rectifiable and we call the supremum the length of the path. In the differentiable case this reduces to the integral over the norm of the derivative. The triangle inequality makes it obvious that the direct path is the shortest.

Answer (score 3):

Parametrize an arbitrary path by $r(t)$ on $t\in[a,b]$ that is differentiable a.e. on $(a,b)$. Then by triangle inequality

$$\big\|r(b)-r(a) \big\|=\big\|\int_a^br'(t)dt \big\|\leq\int_a^b\big\|r'(t) \big\|dt.$$

LHS is distance of a line segment connecting two points; RHS is distance of an arbitrary path.

Comment: oh and we still need to show that the straight line has length $\|r(b)-r(a)\|$

Comment: I also wonder what the definition of a path length is. If you define it by the integral over the normed derivative, then this is fine. But how would you measure non differentiable paths then...

Comment: @FelixB. As for your first point, why do you think it is not immediate that the LHS is the length of a straight line? $r(b)-r(a)$ is the vector connecting the end points. As for your second point, if the path is not differentiable a.e., we allow for things like fractals, which technically have infinite length.

Comment: But why is the length of a vector $v$ equal to the length of the path $\gamma(t) = tv$ for $t\in[0,1]$? Somehow we have to translate lengths of vectors to lengths of paths. And I am starting to get the feeling, that any reasonable translation is going to be circular. I.e. to get a reasonable definition, we are going to *assume* that the length of the straight line path is equal to the vector, at which point it becomes more of a definition that the straight line is shortest...

Comment: @Golden_Ratio does your proof use the Triangle Inequality? I guess your proof uses Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. Of course the Triangle Inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality are similar inequalities.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot decide which answer is best.

Comment: @FelixB. Hm, not sure I follow. $\|r(b)-r(a)\|$ is path-independent and is the parametric equivalent of the usual Cartesian  notion of "straight line" distance between two points (parametrized by $r(b)$ and $r(a)$). Likewise, the RHS is the parametric equivalent of the usual arc length integral formula. I am not sure where you see in this setup that a straight line being the shortest path is taken as definitional.

Comment: @tchappyha If we consider an integral as a limiting Riemann sum, is it not the vanilla triangle inequality? See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103779/proof-involving-norm-of-an-integral

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you very much for the link.